# Error in uploading blob in Azure storage account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I'm using below code to create Azure container.

```
    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cs);
   blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();        
    CloudBlobContainer con1 = CreateContainer("container1", false);
```

But I am getting following error while creating Container in Azure:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
```

Note: I have followed Azure naming conventions for creating containers. All are in lower case letters but still getting error. Please suggest next steps.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for your `CreateContainer` method? Also, please tell us the exact name of the container you're trying to create.

Comment: Any update of this question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the package you are using is deprecated ([WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/)).

You may try to use the newest [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs). The code sample you need seems to be this: [Create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#create-a-container) :)

Despite the suggestion, in which instruction are you getting the error? If you can, please provide more details, since the application of the suggested example may or may not solve your problem.

Comment: How is using the new package is going to help OP? Even with the new package, 400 error would still come.

Comment: The bad request may come from several sources, you are right. With the provided sample, no further analysis can be made, but the renew of the package can already be suggested, since the package has in fact been deprecated for some time. But I edited the answer to ask for more details, if they exist :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Below code works fine on my side(I use the package that your error shows):

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp55
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cs);
            var blobclient= storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer con1 = blobclient.GetContainerReference("test0419");
            await con1.CreateAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

If still don't work, please show more details.

**Original Answer:**

From your error, it seems you are using old package reference.

The newest package reference tutorials is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#code-examples

And please make sure you didn't create the container before.

Comment: How is using the new package is going to help OP? Even with the new package, 400 error would still come.